# How to select first section of order number

Tags: sql

I want to make a view on a table that has the order number as length 10 digits.
I want the first 8.

```
Select PkgWeight, Order_Num
  from ylib.shipping
 where date > 20140101
```

How do I say that I want only digits 1-8 on the `order_num`?

Comment: Which SQL vendor are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc. Please note this in your question as answers can vary from one to another.

Comment: What is the type of the order number column?  Is it a numeric type (in which case the integer portion of `order_num / 100` will give you what you want), or is it a string type (in which case `SUBSTR(order_num, 1, 8)` or something similar will give you what you want)?  Also, your date comparison is a little laid-back; are you sure that you've got the correct types of expression for that?

Comment: If using sql server then SELECT TOP 8 * FROM ylib.shipping WHERE date > 2014101

Comment: I think he means 12345678 from 1234567890 not an 8 row limit

Answer (score 1):

```
left(order_num,8)
```

will return the first chars of the string.

Comment: Which DBMS support this?

Comment: This is supported in MS SQL